# watching myself everywhere?

Tags: anatman, self

During meditation sessions, morning 4 to 5, I have started watching myself everywhere. I didn't experienced it before. The garden where I am used to take a morning walk after meditation, there I saw my duplicates, same me in different-2 attire, casual-formal-pyjamas-with friends-cycling.
There was a moment in real world when I thought that if I could see everyone as me then I can percieve real peace. I think that thought merged into meditation and showed me the same but it was very different. I was so attached to myself when no one other was present as a special appearance. I want to know 'was that of my thought was wrong or right ?

Comment: My english is still weak. Don't hassitate make a correction. I'd be thankful. Regards & Love.

Answer (score 2):

When meditating you might get imaginative experiences which might seem very real. Just do not give any importance to them. Just be aware that you are experiencing something. These experiences has sensations associated and if you get attached to them unsatisfactory experiences will follow. Whenever you get some experience just see if you like or dislike or neutral towards the experience and the sensations that follows.

Comment: I myself manytimes, give suggestions to other just per my own Experience. I am here at buddism section to get references of his, the buddha's real teachings. Please try get me into that on this matter if it is there in buddhism. Regards & Love.

Comment: Best is that you take a course http://dhamma.org

Comment: Thank you. My phone isn't compatible. Once I will complete that, i'd be back. Regards & Love Sir.